# Splitting polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring

I have a polynomial ${\frac{{{{({z^2})}^p} \pm {p^p}}}{{{z^2} \pm p}}}$ where $p$ is an odd prime number, and I know it splits into two factors $$ \sum_{i = 0}^{p - 1} a_i z^i \text{ and } \sum_{i = 0}^{p - 1} ( - 1)^i  a_i z^i $$

For example, when $p=5$
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{x^{10}-5^5}{x^2-5} &=& x^8+5x^6+25x^4+125x^2+625\\  
&=& (x^4 + 5x^3+15x^2+25x+25)(x^4-5x^3+15x^2-25x+25)
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Does anyone know a nice method for determining these two factoring polynomials?

Comment: Does the choice of sign depend on the residue class of $p$ modulo $4$?

Comment: The factorization exists, iff the sign is equal to $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}$. Given that, one factor is 
$$\prod_{j=1}^{p-1}\left(x-\left(\frac k p \right)\zeta_p^k\sqrt{p*}\right),$$
where $\zeta_p=e^{2\pi i/p}$, $p^*=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p$ and $(\frac k p )$ is the Legendre symbol. The other factor is gotten by switching the signs of the zeros. But I guess you knew that, and would like to see a closed formula for the coefficients :-)

Comment: Do you have any other examples?

Comment: @lhf, Also sprach Mathematica:
For $p=7$ we get
$$x^{14}+7^7=\left( 7 + {x^2} \right) \,
  \left( 343 - 343\,x + 147\,{x^2} - 49\,{x^3} + 
    21\,{x^4} - 7\,{x^5} + {x^6} \right) \,
  \left( 343 + 343\,x + 147\,{x^2} + 49\,{x^3} + 
    21\,{x^4} + 7\,{x^5} + {x^6} \right)$$
and for $p=3$
$$
x^6+3^3=\left( 3 + {x^2} \right) \,
  \left( 3 - 3\,x + {x^2} \right) \,
  \left( 3 + 3\,x + {x^2} \right).$$

Comment: Thanks; this is very helpful. I assume that the product should go from $k=1$ and not $j=1$. I am definitely looking for a closed formula for the coefficients.

Comment: @BudgieJane, indeed, that was a silly typo. Thinking...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, thanks. I couldn't get Wolfram Alpha to do this, though now I can :-)

Comment: I can't help thinking this is related to the Aurifeullian factorizations. See, e.g., http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AurifeuilleanFactorization.html, although I think there's more to Aurifeullian factorization than what's to be found at that site.

Comment: Sorry, @Gerry, I should have mentioned: yes it is all related to Aurifeuillian factorization and cyclotomic polynomials.

Comment: The coefficients of those polynomials are mildly complicated exponentials sums. I can't evaluate them at this time (other than Gauss' sums). It is easy to see that (after you strip the factor $\sqrt{p^*}$ from the zeros) that the coefficients are alternately either integers or integer multiples of $\sqrt{p^*}$, but finding a formula takes more time than I can invest on this at this time (and I may not be man enough to do it anyway). Sorry, Jane. Thanks for an interesting question!

Comment: Oh my gosh; I seem to have found some sort of solution. It involves Lucas's formula for Cyclotomic Polynomials (see Riesel, Table 24).

Comment: @Jyrki: Thanks for all your help, it is most appreciated.

Comment: Another example, for $p=11$ is$$161051 + 161051x + 73205x^2 + 14641x^3  -1331x^4  -1331x^5  -121x^6 + 121x^7 + 55x^8 + 11x^9 + x^{10}$$ together with its companion where the signs of the coefficients of the odd powers of x are reversed.

Comment: If you have found a solution, write it up and post it as an answer! May seem strange, but answering your own questions is explicitly encouraged around here.

Comment: It's not the sort of solution I was expecting. I was hoping to see something along the lines of extracting square roots by long division (yes, I know this is not a square root, but there are some things in common with square roots), and this solution doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution I found, which to me is unsatisfactory.

This solution uses Table 24 from Riesel’s “Prime Numbers and Computer Methods for Factorization”. Look up the number you are interested in in the *n* column, and note down the two sets of coefficients given there: they are $U_n(x)$ and $V_n(x)$. Multiply each coefficient in $U_n(x)$ by $p^0$, $p^1$, $p^2$, …, $p^{p-1}$, and those in $V_n(x)$ by $p^1$, $p^2$, … $p^{p-1}$. Then take a coefficient from each list alternately and you have your factor. Do the same for the other factor after multiplying $V_n(x)$ by $-1$.

Example for $p=11$:
$U_n(x)=1, 5, -1, -1, 5, 1$
$V_n(x)=1, 1, -1, 1, 1$
Multiplying by powers of $11$:
$U_n = 1, 55, -121, -1331, 73205, 161051\\
V_n = 11, 121, -1331, 14641, 161051$
Taking the coefficients one at a time from each list one factor is
$$x^{10} + 11x^9 +55x^8 +121x^7 -121x^6 -1331x^5 -1331x^4 +14641x^3 +73205x^2 +161051x +161051$$
and the other factor is

$$x^{10} - 11x^9 +55x^8 -121x^7 -121x^6 +1331x^5 -1331x^4 -14641x^3 +73205x^2 -161051x +161051$$

Comment: Can you prove that this works in general?

Comment: There is clearly a connection with the factorization cyclotomic polynomials over $\mathbb Z$ because if you set $z=\sqrt{p}w$ then your polynomials are $p^{p-1}\dfrac{(w^2)^p\pm1}{w^2\pm1}$. It seems that $\Phi_p(x^2)$ can be further factorized than $\Phi_p(x)$.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclotomicPolynomial.html , eq 17 and 37.

Comment: I think I could prove it if I put my mind to it. Howeveer, I'm not too bothered, as this is not the solution I'm looking for. (Maybe what I'm looking for is unobtainable).  
Your second comment here mirrors what's in Paul Garrett's paper. See my comments to the next solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a follow-up from my comment, but unfortunately it does not work. Since it is too long for a comment, I leave it here as an answer.

Set $z=\lambda x$, where $\lambda= \sqrt{p}$ for convenience. Then your polynomials are $p^{p-1}\dfrac{(x^2)^p\pm1}{x^2\pm1}$.

Now $(x^2)^p-1=x^{2p}-1=\Phi_{2p}(x)\Phi_p(x)\Phi_2(x)\Phi_1(x)=\Phi_p(-x)\Phi_p(x)(x^2-1)$, where $\Phi_n$ is the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial.

Then $p^{p-1}\dfrac{((x^2)^p-1)}{x^2-1}=\lambda^{2p-2}\Phi_p(-x)\Phi_p(x)=(\lambda^{p-1}\Phi_p(-x))(\lambda^{p-1}\Phi_p(x))=Q(-z)Q(z)$, where $Q(z)=\lambda^{p-1}\Phi_p(x)=\lambda^{p-1}\Phi_p(z/\lambda)$.

This is the correct form from the original observations. Unfortunately, $Q$ does *not* have integer coefficients. The factorization obtained for the case $p=5$ does *not* come from this one. And there goes my idea...

*Edit*: I've now found that all this is discussed on page 6 of these [notes](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/number_theory/aurifeuillian.pdf) by Paul Garrett. I think this is the best answer to the question.

Comment: +1 While playing, I got the impression that this has to with the factorization of $\Phi_{2p}(x)$ over the unique quadratic intermediate field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p^*})$. Have you ever seen that?

Comment: @lhf: My original question was motivated by Paul Garrett's paper, which is why I'm looking for a different sort of solution. I admit that what I'm looking for may be unobtainable, but I figure there's no harm in looking.

Comment: @Jyrki: Yes, and lhf seems to be suggesting that too.

Comment: @BudgieJane, you might have mentioned Garrett's paper...